# Split the output of GetNameSpace("MAPI") in VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm learning VBscript to assist creating user forms in outlook. With this appointment form I'm attempting to create a pre-formatted email signed off with the name of the current user. I only want the output to be the current users first name. It is currently returning the full name.

How can I split the user name or get only the users first name?

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub commandbutton1_click()
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem
set prop = item.userproperties.find("Mobile")
set currentuser = application.getNameSpace("MAPI").CurrentUser
Set prop1 = item.userProperties.find("Subject")
Set prop2 = item.userProperties.find("Location")
Set prop3 = item.userProperties.find("DateStart")

dteThen = dateAdd("h", -1, Now())

With MyItem
                .To = prop & "@etxt.co.nz"
                .Subject = ""
                .Body = "Hi " & Subject & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & "This is a reminder about your meeting at " & Location & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & "Thanks" & currentUser
                .DeferredDeliveryTime = DateStart + dteThen
End With
MyItem.Display
end sub
```

Comment: Please show a sample of how the name is displayed.. likewhat value you get in the currentuser variable

Comment: Thanks for your response. The name is displayed as follows: (Last name), (First Name) i.e. Smith, John. At the moment this generates an email that says "Thanks Smith, John". I just need it to be "Thanks John". I can't work out how to get a split function to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly simple...

```
Sub commandbutton1_click()
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem
set prop = item.userproperties.find("Mobile")
set currentuser = application.getNameSpace("MAPI").CurrentUser
Set prop1 = item.userProperties.find("Subject")
Set prop2 = item.userProperties.find("Location")
Set prop3 = item.userProperties.find("DateStart")
arrUserName = Split(currentUser, ",") 'Split the name using "," 
strName = Trim(arrUserName(1))   'Remove any space

dteThen = dateAdd("h", -1, Now())

With MyItem
                .To = prop & "@etxt.co.nz"
                .Subject = ""

                .Body = "Hi " & Subject & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & "This is a reminder about your meeting at " & Location & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & "Thanks," & vbcrLF & strName 'use of strName
                .DeferredDeliveryTime = DateStart + dteThen
End With
MyItem.Display
end sub
```